# Using neo4j-jdbc open-connection is bottleneck

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, connection-pooling, spring-data-neo4j

I am using neo4-jdbc with pool lib BasicDataSource.

I had huge latency problems so we profiled the app and we found out that opening connection is the cause. I didnt understand why open-connection takes so long we using pool. this is screenshot from our profiles:

[image]

This is how the Neo4jDatasourceRemote looks like:

```
package com.comp.wm.common.repo;

import com.comp.wm.common.utils.Constants;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;




    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Neo4jDataSourceRemote.class);

    private BasicDataSource ds;

    @Value("${neo4j.host:localhost}")
    private String NEO4J_HOST;

    @Value("${neo4j.port:7474}")
    private String NEO4J_PORT;

    @Value("${neo4j.username:nouser}")
    private String NEO4J_USERNAME;

    @Value("${neo4j.password:nopass}")
    private String NEO4J_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${neo4j.pool.size:200}")
    private int NEO4J_POOL_SIZE;

    private String GetUrl() {
        return String.format(Constants.NEO4J_JDBC_CONNECTIVITY_STRING, NEO4J_HOST, NEO4J_PORT);
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setInitialSize(300);
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl(GetUrl());
        ds.setUsername(NEO4J_USERNAME);
        ds.setPassword(NEO4J_PASSWORD);
    }


    @Override
    public Connection openConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.ds.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.info("error closing connection", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is a sample of how I execute query against the graph:

```
public List<NearbyItem> executeQuery(..) {
        conn = neo4jDataSource.openConnection();


        String getUsersStatement = "some query..";

        try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(getUsersStatement)) {
           ..
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
               ...
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error returning userId=" + userIdInput, e);
        } finally {
            neo4jDataSource.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return distItemDatas;
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: how many concurrent actions are you running? By default Neo4j uses 10 threads per core on http level. If you have more active connections open, new ones need to wait.

Comment: I am running like 120 concurrent requests per second executing same action

Comment: How can I increase neo4j 10 threads per core default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments above, I'll add this as a reply.

By default Neo4j runs in the http interface 10 threads for core. You can tweak the total number of threads in `neo4j-server.properties`

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads=200
```

However the more threads you have the more you're suffering from context switches and lock contention. If you increase the number of threads I won't expect a large increase of throughput, you just shift the point where you have to wait. From initialization (openCOnnection) to processing the query.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do? For each request I am waiting much more. how I should increase throughput and decrease latency ?

Comment: Tune cypher queries, improve data model, add cores, scale out using enterprise cluster.... There is a huge variety on what you can do.

Comment: I am using neo4j hosted by Grapehn DB. as you know we cant scale neo4j but using more slaves. I am using barely 100 requests per sec with simple query and already have latency issues.. abit worry